# Not writing to the file Scala

Tags: file, scala, io

I have the following code, which is supposed to write to a file one line at a time, until it reaches ^EOF.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.io.File
object WF {
  def writeline(file: String)(delim: String): Unit = {
    val writer = new PrintWriter(new File(file))
    val line = Console.readLine(delim)
    if (line != "^EOF") {
      writer.write(line + "\n")
      writer.flush()
    }
    else {
      sys.exit()
    }
  }
}
var counter = 0
val filename = Console.readLine("Enter a file: ")
while (true) {
  counter += 1
  WF.writeline(filename)(counter.toString + ": ")
}
```

For some reason, at the console, everything looks like it works fine, but then, when I actually read the file, nothing has been written to it! What is wrong with my program?

Answer (score 3):

Every time you create a new `PrintWriter` you're wiping out the existing file. Use something like a [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29), which allows you to specify that you want to open the file for appending:

```
val writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File(file), true))
```

That should work, although the logic here is pretty confusing.

Comment: The only reason to wrap the FileWriter in a PrintWriter would be if you wanted to use the print/printf methods or the auto-flush, which he isn't.

Comment: @brandon: I just assumed there was some reason the author was using a `PrintWriter` to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Use `val writer = new FileWriter(new File(file), true)` instead.  The second parameter tells the FileWriter to append to the file.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is that you forgot to close the writer.